# Change name of checkbox label if its open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Hello I want to change the name of my checkbox based on it's state. I want it to say Open it the box is not checked and Close if the box is checked. I have tried the below JS but it is not working.

my html

```
    <div class="box">
      <h3 class="name">Jon Do</h3>
      <p class="title">smaple title</p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tabs" id="tab-one">
      <label for="tab-one">open</label>
      <div class="teamBio">
        <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

my javascript

```
if($("#tab-one").checked {
  $(".tab-one").text("close");
  else {
  $(".tab-one").text("open");
  }
})
```

Comment: You should add the 'jQuery' tag to the question since you're looking for a jQuery solution to this. There are pure javascript solutions to this too in the answers regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome. You are on the right track. I added a class to your label and referenced it in your JS. Also you have some errors in your JS, you can't say `if($("#tab-one").checked` etc. See below:

HTML:

```
   <div class="box">
      <h3 class="name">Jon Do</h3>
      <p class="title">smaple title</p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tabs" id="tab-one">
      <label for="tab-one" class="trigger">Open</label>
      <div class="teamBio">
        <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
   var trigger = $('.trigger');

    trigger.click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("selected");
      if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $(this).text("Close");
      } else {
        $(this).text("Open");
      }
    });
```

Comment: @p0rk you're welcome. for reference, the other answers given below will work also

Comment: except that this doesn't work if they click *on the checkbox*, only if they click on the label.

Comment: @dave you're right. i assumed he was hiding the checkbox, and using the label as a trigger to show/hide the `div.teamBio`. i suppose i should not assume this.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you would use either `$.is(':checked')` or `$.prop('checked')`, `.checked` is vanilla js, which you could use if you did `$('#tab-one')[0].checked`.  Also, your label doesn't have a `class="tab-one"`, so you need to either add it, or change your `$('.tab-one')` to `$('[for="tab-one"]')`.

You would probably want to do it like this:

```js
$('#tab-one').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(".tab-one").text("close");
    } else {
        $(".tab-one").text("open");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
      <h3 class="name">Jon Do</h3>
      <p class="title">smaple title</p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tabs" id="tab-one">
      <label class="tab-one" for="tab-one">open</label>
      <div class="teamBio">
        <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the desired output, or reversed?

```js
$("#tab-one").change(function(){
  var label = "open";
  if ($(this).prop('checked'))
     label = "close";
  $('label[for="tab-one"]').text(label);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
      <h3 class="name">Jon Do</h3>
      <p class="title">smaple title</p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tabs" id="tab-one">
      <label for="tab-one">open</label>
      <div class="teamBio">
        <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a pure javascript solution, you can add an event listener to the checkbox and use `textContent` to update it like this:

```js
const checkBox = document.getElementById('tab-one');
const label = document.querySelector('label');

function toggleText(){
 if (this.checked){
   label.textContent = 'open';
  } else {
   label.textContent = 'close';
  }

}

checkBox.addEventListener('click', toggleText);
```

```html
    <div class="box">
      <h3 class="name">Jon Do</h3>
      <p class="title">smaple title</p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tabs" id="tab-one">
      <label for="tab-one">close</label>
      <div class="teamBio">
        <p>content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/gpLm7487/

Answer (score 1):

While you ask for a JavaScript, or jQuery, solution it's worth pointing out that this is possible using HTML and CSS:

```
// setting the default state for the .teamBio
// element's display, for when the checkbox
// is unchecked:
#tab-one~.teamBio {
  display: none;
}

// setting the display of the .teamBio
// element's display for when the checkbox
// is checked; using the ':checked' UI
// element pseudo-class:
#tab-one:checked~.teamBio {
  display: block;
}

// Using the '::before' pseudo-element, with
// CSS generated content, to set text for the
// checkbox's next-sibling ('+') <label>
// element:
#tab-one+label::before {
  content: 'Open';
}

// setting the generated content of the <label>
// for when the checkbox element is checked:
#tab-one:checked+label::before {
  content: 'Close';
}
```

```css
#tab-one~.teamBio {
  display: none;
}

#tab-one:checked~.teamBio {
  display: block;
}

#tab-one+label::before {
  content: 'Open';
}

#tab-one:checked+label::before {
  content: 'Close';
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h3 class="name">Jon Do</h3>
  <p class="title">sample title</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="tabs" id="tab-one">
  <label for="tab-one"></label>
  <div class="teamBio">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```